# Rendering multiple files on bottle web server

Tags: python, html, css, bottle

I am trying to render a couple of files on Bottle web server. The first HTML file has a button which links to another file. So I need both of these to run on the server.
My (updated)Project structure is something like this

```
   -app.py
   -static
         -css
               bootstrap.css
               bootstrap.min.css
         -fonts
         -js
               jquery.js
               etc etc

  -index.html    
  -visualization.html
```

My `index.html` file has to be rendered first. From which the user has to option to click on a button which takes him to `visualization.html`.

My pages are not rendering. What could be the reason for this?

The routing snippet from app.py is as show below:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, static_file, response, request

@route('/noob')

    def map():
        return static_file('index.html',root = './static')
    run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8030')
```

This is how I access those files in my `index.html`:

```
<script src="./static/js/jquery.js"></script>

  <link href="./static/css/grayscale.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I'm relatively new to *Python* and *Bottle*. Is this right? I get a *404 error*

.

Also, how to I place two files on the bottle server. As explained above, a button in `index.html` links to visualization.html. So I'm guessing this should also be running on *Bottle* server. Do I run it in the same file? Different port?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put **index.html** in **static** folder.

```
-app.py
-static
     various css and img files being used in my two html files
     index.html    
     visualization.html
```

A better way for accessing static files and templates would be to rename **index.html** to **index.tpl** like this:

```
-app.py
    -static
       -js
         bootstrap.min.js (example)
       -css
       -fonts
 index.tpl    
 visualization.tpl
 profile.tpl
```

And:

```
from bottle import route, run, template, static_file, response, request

@route('/noob')
def map():
    return template('index.tpl')

@route('/profile')
def profile():
    return template('profile.tpl')

@route('/static/<filepath:path>')
def server_static(filepath):
    return static_file(filepath, root='./static/')

run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8030')
```

And in your tpl files use path like this:

```
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I did this. Only my html is getting rendered. The css isn't. Its throwing 404 errors for the CSS, JS and img files.

Comment: Now the server itself does not run.

Comment: What's the error? I guess you're doing something wrong. This works fine for me.

Comment: Not getting any error. When i run my app.py it just returns back to the prompt.

Comment: Have you removed this run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8030') from your code?

Comment: Same problem. No CSS being rendered.

Comment: Please update your answer to include index file with the appropriate paths and your bottle app and let me check again. Thank you

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2016 00:35:27] "GET /css/vegasimage.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 756
127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2016 00:35:27] "GET /css/vegasimage.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 404 756
127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2016 00:36:42] "GET /noob HTTP/1.1" 200 7685
127.0.0.1 - - [02/May/2016 00:36:42] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 774
Some of the errors when the tpl runs

Comment: No, I mean in your question please update your file structure and their contents. Also index.html and app.py.

Comment: I figured out the error. I was running the run command before the second @route.

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to have different routes you can just duplicate  @route('/noob') with a different name and function like I did in the answer